# Lwuit touch screen strange behaviour

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I am making an application using LWUIT.

1. There is a form
2. There is a list embedded on the form.
3. The list has 5 elements.
4. Initially, when I first load the app, if I choose the 1st element, 2nd gets chosen; when I choose the second the 3rd gets chose and and so on (Weird!)
5. I am not able to click any button on the screen either
6. next what I do is, shift to a different from using arrow keys (of the keyboard... I am running the app on a simulator btw)
7. Then I come back to the first form and now everything works as expected(no weird behaviour).
8. What could be the issue?
9. I am using Sun Java Micro Edition SDK 3.0 (default touch screen for testing)

My code is:

```
List dummy = new List();
        dummy.addItem("wewerwer");
        dummy.addItem("wewerdswer");
        dummy.addItem("wewqweerwer");
        dummy.addItem("dscxwewerwer");
        dummy.addItem("jhgwewerwer");
        mainListForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainListForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,dummy);
   mainListForm.show();
```

What could possible be going wrong here?

**UPDATE 1**

I think there is a bug here. I have attached the complete code below along with the screen shot

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

import com.sun.lwuit.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.UIManager;
import com.sun.lwuit.util.Resources;

public class Demo extends MIDlet implements ActionListener {

  private Form mForm;
List abc;
  public void startApp() {

      Display.init(this);

      try {
Resources r = Resources.open("/Test.res");
UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme(
r.getThemeResourceNames()[0])
);
} catch (Exception e){
System.out.println(e.toString());
}

    if (mForm == null) {
      Button click = new Button("Press me!");

      click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                   System.out.println("I have been pressed");
                }
            });
       abc = new List();
      abc.addItem("Str1");
      abc.addItem("Str2");
      abc.addItem("Str3");
      abc.addItem("Str4");
      abc.addItem("Str5");
      abc.addItem("Str6");



      Form f = new Form("Hello, LWUIT!");
      abc.addActionListener(this);
       f.addComponent(abc);
      Command exitCommand = new Command("Exit");
      f.addCommand(exitCommand);
      f.addCommandListener(this);
      f.addComponent(click);
      f.show();
    }
  }

  public void pauseApp() {
  }

  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      System.out.println(abc.getSelectedIndex());

  }
}
```

[image]

So now when I click on 'Str1' of the list Str2 gets selected and so on.

IDE: Netbeans
Emulator: Default Touch screen phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK....so this is how you resolve it.

After the form is displayed remove the list from the form and again add it to the form and then repaint the form.

**Earlier Code**

1) form.addComponenet(BorderLayout.center,list);
2) form.show();

**Word Around for the problem**

1)form.addComponenet(BorderLayout.center,list);
2)form.show(); 
3)form.setScrollable(false);

I know its kind of strange, but this way the list index selection works smooth for touch screen phones.

Answer (score 0):

On the action event set the list to active again after the event by invoking `setHandlesInput(true)`

Comment: hello shai. i think there is a bug here (correct me if am wrong) . When i selected index 1, index 2 gets selected. I have added the code above in UPDATE 1 . I tried setting list.setHandlesInput(true) but well its not working as expected. Please let me know what else should i try....thanks!

Comment: And the weirdest thing is...if i select the last index some index at the top of the list gets selected. This is very annoying. How can i fix it?